# wasting space in page!

Tags: tables, spacing, appendices

I was wondering what could be the problem with an Appendix page? Basically the Appendix has tables but such tables are located in the next pages as in the figure. [image]

As can be seen the tables that follows are small and could fit in the wasted space bellow the Appendix title.

I am using some of the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
% other usepackage...
\include{graficos} %graficos is where the appendix is!
\begin{appendix} %this code from here is in the graficos file...
\chapter{Appendix: Tables}
\begin{table}
%table content
\end{table}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Can I move the table up and no waste space?

Many thanks

Comment: Or `\begin{table}[htbp]` to allow latex to place the table as best as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the `table` environment you're trying to typeset contains a caption, three header rows, and 9 rows in the main part or "body". If so, LaTeX will indeed not place it on the same page as a chapter-level header, as may be confirmed by running the compilable example shown below.

However, if you uncomment the `[h!]` placement specifier, i.e., change `\begin{table}` to `\begin{table}[h!]`, LaTeX will ignore all implicit restrictions on the maximum amount of (vertical) space a `float` is permitted to occupy and typeset the table immediately below the chapter header, thereby meeting your objective.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{appendix} 
\stepcounter{chapter} % just for this example
\chapter{Appendix: Tables}

% Sample table: caption/3 header rows/9 main rows
\begin{table}%[h!]  % <-- uncomment '[h!]' for better result
\centering
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{l}}
\\
\toprule
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
\midrule
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
A & B & C & D & E & F\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```